# How to I configure jenkins to start nodes using another user?

Tags: jenkins

I want to use a NIS account to run jenkins nodes but keep running jenkins on the local user, so it doesn't depend on the NIS account availability.

How can I configure jenkins to try to start the nodes using a different username.

Both master and nodes are Linux machines.

Comment: How do you currently start them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to do it for each ssh started node by going to advanced config.

For this reason it may be easier to arrange jenkins setup in such way that it will use the same username on all machines, so you do not have to trick the setup for each worker.

Shortly, it is much easier to reconfigure jenkins to run as a NIS account: edit `/etc/default/jenkins` and `chown -R xxx:xxx /var/lib/jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration when you setup a new node. First, pick "Run Jenkins as windows service".  The pick "Run Service As", this pops up a user/password field for you to specify the user the service is run as. I've needed to do this with Active Directory accounts to get to network resources.

Comment: Now, really how many Windows systems had you seen that are using NIS? I'm on Linux :)

Comment: Sorry, I know a bit about LDAP, but not familiar with NIS.  Have you tried running the slave as SSH and use that login and password?